# Way to trigger dataflow only after Big Query Job finished

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

actually the following steps to my data:

new objects in GCS bucket trigger a Google Cloud function that create a BigQuery Job to load this data to BigQuery.

I need low cost solution to know when this Big Query Job is finished and  trigger a Dataflow Pipeline only after the job is completed.

Obs:

- I know about BigQuery alpha trigger for Google Cloud Function but i
  dont know if is a good idea,from what I saw this trigger uses the job
  id, which from what I saw can not be fixed and whenever running a job
  apparently would have to deploy the function again. And of course
  it's an alpha solution.
- I read about a Stackdriver Logging->Pub/Sub -> Google cloud  function -> Dataflow  solution, but i didn't find any log that
  indicates that the job finished.
- My files are large so isn't a good idea to use a Google Cloud Function to wait until the job finish.

Comment: Actually i noticed that i need the "Private Logs Viewer" role to see jobcompleted log in Logging. So actually i am tending to use the stackdriver logging solution.

Comment: You want to run a dataflow for each integrated file? Or after the load of all your files?

Comment: What I wound do, even if not perfect is create a cloud function that runs every once in a while and checks the job id via bq api to see if it completed. If so, run the dataflow pipeline with dataflow admin sdk. You can use the datastore as a queue for tracking your job ids and cloud sheduler to create your cron job.

Comment: Have you considered doing all of the steps in one Dataflow pipeline? Then it is pretty easy to do things in sequential steps.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere run dataflow for  each table generated by file(with custom query), my objective.

Comment: @Pievis We consider this option but we believe it can become a problem beyond unnecessary processing costs.

Comment: @KennKnowles Actually  i think that our step to migrate GCS to  BQ is very less expensive with Big Query Jobs than with dataflow. We are talking about  big files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your mention about Stackdriver logging, you can use it with this filter

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.state="DONE"
severity="INFO"
```

*You can add dataset filter in addition if needed.*

Then create a sink into Function on this advanced filter and run your dataflow job.

If this doesn't match your expectation, can you detail why?

Comment: This is our strategy right now, we were having an error seeing this log due to the lack of the "Private Log Viewer" role.

Comment: Where do you have this issue? When you create your sink?

Comment: I already solved this issue. To see the "jobCompleted" logs i need an expecific permission that  "Private Log Viewer" role (in IAM) have. Thanks i think  now that the  solution Stackdriver-> pubsub-> Google cloud Function-> Dataflow its the best for my problem. Thanks  its solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Cloud Composer which is managed Apache Airflow for orchestrating jobs in a sequential fashion. Composer creates a DAG and executes each node of the DAG and also checks for dependencies to ensure that things either run in parallel or sequentially based on the conditions that you have defined.

You can take a look at the example mentioned here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/cloud-composer-examples/composer_dataflow_examples

Comment: Composer was one of our options, but we gave up of it cause of his price.